# Proper way to add useEffect in react to call once to satisfy eslint react-hooks/exhaustive-deps?

Tags: reactjs, eslint

I'm using eslint [react-hooks/exhaustive-deps](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14920) the problem I'm having is my component needs to call only once regardless of changes on props. It is fine with `[]` but when using dependencies it is called multiple time.

my code is (with some omitted)

- parents

```
// some logic for tracking change in realtime
<Component trackingObject=tracking />
```

- children:

```
export default function Component(props){
  // if I use depedencies, it will called multiple times because 
  // trackingCode keep changing
  React.useEffect(()=>{
    // some code
    // fetch function
   const _updateSession = async () => {
      const tracking = props.trackingObject;

      const formData = new URLSearchParams();
      formData.append('trackingCode', tracking.trackingCode);
      formData.append('sessionCode', tracking.sessionCode);
      formData.append('content', trackingStage);

      try {
        const req = await fetch(`https://example.com/tracking/${tracking.id}/`, {
          method: 'PUT',
          body: formData,
        })
        const res = await req.json();

        switch (req.status) {
          case 200:
            props.setQuestion('trackingObject', res);
            break
        }

      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
      }
    }
   _updateSession()
  },[props.trackingObject]) 
  // if props.trackingObject is ommited like so [] it works just fine
 

  return (
  <>
    // some code 
  </>)
}
```

I tried to use `useRef` but somehow the `trackingObject` is empty. Is there a way to satisfy the dependencies without making it call multiple times?

thanks

Comment: it's a fetch function, updated it

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Where did you use `props.trackingCode` in `useEffect` body?

Comment: fix it, it should be trackingObject not trackingCode , my question still stands.

Answer (score -1):

Proper way is that if you want to execute the useEffect at once just don't pass the dependencies  in in dependency array. I know you mentioned it but its right way.
If you want to run useEffect on state change then pass the state variable in dependency array.

```
React.useEffect(()=>{
    // some code
    // fetch function
   const _updateSession = async () => {
      const tracking = props.trackingObject;

      const formData = new URLSearchParams();
      formData.append('trackingCode', tracking.trackingCode);
      formData.append('sessionCode', tracking.sessionCode);
      formData.append('content', trackingStage);

      try {
        const req = await fetch(`https://example.com/tracking/${tracking.id}/`, {
          method: 'PUT',
          body: formData,
        })
        const res = await req.json();

        switch (req.status) {
          case 200:
            props.setQuestion('trackingObject', res);
            break
        }

      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
      }
    }
   _updateSession()
  },[])
```